# to anyone whosoever vs. whomever — without a following verb

Tags: difference, legalese, archaic-language

Is *whosoever* interchangeable with *whomsoever*? Please see the 6 examples below; they seem like similar situations but some use *whosoever* and some use *whomsoever*.

### to anyone whosoever

> *Reliability:* If these statements are taken as universal claims , applying to anyone **whosoever**, they are easily shown to be false .

1. John Burbidge, *Within Reason: A Guide to Non-Deductive Reasoning*, [Page 158](https://books.google.com/books?id=BqJZAAAAYAAJ&q=%22to+anyone+whosoever%22&dq=%22to+anyone+whosoever%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9otTIz9LzAhXrSt8KHXN_CnY4ZBDoAXoECBoQAg).

> Kant was astute to observe a discrepancy between what the judge
> says and what he intends. But this goes on, in his opinion, within a
> social world of many intending subjects, such that the judge, aware of the
> social context of his judgment, attributes to anyone **whosoever** (*jeder-
> mann*), indeed *demands* of anyone whosoever, agreement with his own
> judgment of the beautiful. This early form of language analysis does not
> suggest that the judge at certain moments is more nearly "at one with the
> One" in a perception that makes profundity interchangeable between a
> quality of an object and a feeling of its finder.

2. Jean Gabbert Harrell, *Profundity
   A Universal Value*, [p 173](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Profundity/FQ7Nt27QPC8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to+anyone+whosoever%22&pg=PA173&printsec=frontcover).

> For example, in
> 'every human being is an animal' the subject term
> has *confused and distributive* supposition, for this is
> a good inference: 'Every human being is an animal;
> therefore, this human being is an animal, and that
> human being is an animal' and so on for each case.  Also this is not formally a good inference: 'this human being (where we point to anyone **whosoever**) is an animal; therefore, every human being is an animal.

3. Martin M. Tweedale, *Basic Issues in Medieval Philosophy* - Second Edition 2006, [p 215](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Basic_Issues_in_Medieval_Philosophy_Seco/JaZaDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to+anyone+whosoever%22&pg=PA215&printsec=frontcover), first paragraph at the top, above "***", on the right hand column.

### to anyone whomsoever

> 3. Do not discuss anything about this case, or even mention it to
>    anyone **whomsoever**, including your wife or husband nor permit
>    anyone to mention it in your hearing until you are discharged as jurors
>    or excused from this case. If anyone attempts to discuss the case, report
>    it to me at once.

4. Josef F. Buenker, *The Interpreter's Guide to the Vehicular Accident Lawsuit*, p 168.

> Some pastoral texts acknowledge openly the threat that allowing any-
> one to correct sin may seem to pose to power relations. In his *Summa
> de poenitentia* (1295), the German Franciscan Johann von Erfürt begins
> to explore the question of who may correct sinners by admitting that it
> seems that the practice should not be open to anyone **whomsoever** — the
> standard scholastic method of entertaining objections to the position the
> writer will advocate.

5. Edwin D Craun, *Ethics and Power in Medieval English Reformist Writing*, [p 31](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ethics_and_Power_in_Medieval_English_Ref/2Sx3M960890C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to+anyone+whomsoever%22&pg=PA31&printsec=frontcover).

> Once in the street, he stood for some time on the pavement,
> wondering whether, after all, he was not an ass not to have discharged his
> pistol. And then he decided that to talk to anyone **whomsoever** about the
> Bellegardes would be extremely disagreeable to him. The least
> disagreeable thing, under the circumstances, was to banish them from his
> mind, and never think of them again.

6. Henry James, *The American*, [Chapter XXV](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/literature/a/the-american/summary-and-analysis/chapter-xxv/chapter-xxv-2). [Anyone know the pg number?](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_American/MZshHxP3NWcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to+anyone+whomsoever%22&pg=PT241&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: ...to anyone at all...

Comment: People have started using *who* instead of *whom*, and concomitantly, they have started using *whosoever* instead of *whomsoever*. All those instances above "should" be *whomsoever* by 19th century grammar rules.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Oxford dictionary *whomsoever* is defined as "used instead of of whosoever as the object of a verb or preposition". So that means if whosoever (which means whoever by the way and is not used except in really old books) is not the object of a verb then you cannot use whomsoever.

For example you would say "Whosoever chooses to leave can go" but you cannot say "Whomsoever chooses to leave can go" although both these words are so obsolete that either sentence would sound correct to a native speaker and I would recommend you just use *whoever* and *whomever*.

Comment: "used instead of of whosoever as the object of a verb or preposition" You have an extra "of".